# How can I change the list index of TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-binding, mvc-editor-templates

How can I change the index of HtmlFieldPrefix?

I'm getting `Children[0]` from EditorFor() and I want to make it `Children[@Model.Id]`
or `Children[2].Children[4]` from EditorFor() and I want to make it `Children[@"ParentModel".Id].Children[@Model.Id]`

I won't know the actual prefix until runtime. Preferably there'd be a built-in way to change it?
Or just messing with the string? I'm still new to C# string functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try putting the following inside your editor template:

```
@model SomeViewModel
@{        
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = Regex.Replace(
        ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, 
        @"\[[0-9]+\]$", 
        m => string.Format("[{0}]", Model.Id)
    );
}
```

Comment: That's great! I figured it was a regular expression kind of thing. Thanks for showing me how.

Comment: lovely solution. I dislike mvc because it has not everything in it, But it has flexibility to do almost anythings you want.